# Comparing two distributions with high variance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance

Lets say I have the following data.

[image: Ovserved data for event A, B, and C]

The Above is the observed data for event A, B, and C.

[image]

And the above is the predicted data for event A, B, and C.

Objective is to compare how my predicted data distribution is close to the observed data distribution for the same event.
The observed data has very high variance by nature, and the number observation for each event varies and more observation could be regarded as more reliable.

Since the data has very high variance in nature, comparing them with statistical value such as mean could be highly inaccurate. I assume I need to compare them by their distribution.

What would be good method to compare two data distribution with such characteristics?

Comment: Can you give more insight into what are A,B and C ? And What do you mean by "compare" the three variables? There are, I guess, infinitely many ways to compare predicted with observed...

Comment: So you essentially created density forecasts for your events, then sampled from these forecasts, giving you your "Predicted", right? And now you would like to see how these samples compare to the actual multiple samples from the true data generating process? Could you also go back to the original density forecasts? It sounds like you are looking for proper [tag:scoring-rules] (take a look at the tag wiki).